# Change highlight menu items on hover to underline on hover on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having some difficulty tying to change the how the menu items would look as once hovered over. Currently it is set to highlight when hovered over but I would like it to be underlined instead.

[image]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: [website link](https://dylogue.com)

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text-decoration: underline;` on hover and remove the color definetion :

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**As I see it override by other css so use `!important`**

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: black!important;
    text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

**EDIT**

> Can i increase the weight/thickness of the underline

**Use `border-bottom` instead `text-decoration`**

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: black!important;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: tekk me for more help

Comment: Can i increase the weight/thickness of the underline?

Comment: this solved it thanks, however is there a way to change the color of the underline only ? I tried `color: rgb(30,115,190)!important;` but it changes the menu word's color as well. Also, when on any tab page (history/politics etc.) the tab in the menu remains permanently highlighted, is there a way to change this to permanently underlined instead?? basically it should function somewhat like this [sample website](http://fbc9e6e8.envatohostedview.com/)

Comment: to change the color of bottom set your color instead `black` `border-bottom: 10px solid yourColor;`

Comment: to stay the bottom border when tab is active use `:focus` :`.navbar-nav > li > a:focus{border-bottom: 10px solid yourColor; }`

Comment: hi, thanks for the help :) 
however `.navbar-nav > li > a:focus{border-bottom: 10px solid yourColor; }` does not seem to work, the tab in the menu remains permanently highlighted instead of underlined when on a tab page

Comment: try to use `:active`

Comment: then in css use `.active{...}`